# is it possible access to specified actions from partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to create partial view with specified actions and use there in the partial view

is it possible?

i cant access and get HTTP Error 404 :(

```
<form method="post" id="upload" action="http://localhost:3909/myControllName/Upload">
```

in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] uploads, string Noe)
```

Comment: Is that method marked with `[HttpPost]`? And do not hard code the full path - its just `action = "@Url.Action("Upload", "yourControllerName")`

Comment: `action="http://localhost:3909/myControllName/Upload"` don't do this. What happens when your site goes live and now the address is `http://www.example.com/myControllName/Upload`? You don't want to make different versions of your code for each environment. Use the Url.Action method as suggested.